# Random Forest and appropriateness of Leave-One-Out

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, validation

I have a classification problem (A, B or C) that appears to be handled well by Random Forest (7 explanatory variables).

I've read that some people find it inappropriate to use Leave-One-Out (L-O-O) for cross-validation purposes. They say there is a minimum fraction of hold outs that are required.

Okay, but my uninformed brain tells me L-O-O is attractive because besides forming an overall assessment about the generalizability this Random Forest approach, I would like to share one, final categorization for each entry as A, B, or C membership. It seems like L-O-O would be basing the calls on something closer to the "final model" compared to model(s) with 20% or other proportion held out.

I'm interested in your views. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although LOO Cross Validation is an approximately unbiased estimator the generalization performance, it has two major drawbacks:

- it has high variance (since all the datasets used for the estimation are highly similar one another;
- it is expensive to compute (it requires $n$ estimates, where $n$ is the number of observations in the dataset).

This is best described in the classic Hastie and Tibshirani book [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf), Chapter 7.10 (where it is also written that 5 or 10 fold cross validation is a good compromise between unbiasedness and computational requirements, and points out to other resources to learn about it).